# I want to remove all duplicates in an array and then write the results to an empty array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I want to remove all duplicates in an array and then write the results to an empty array.

Here is what I have so far...

```
String arIndex[] = new String[rows];    
String value[]; //This is my empty array


for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if (Arrays.asList(value).contains(arIndex)) {
        out.println("Already Exist!");
    } else {
        asList[i] = value[i];
    }
}
```

Could someone give me an idea on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any limitation on what to use?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Arrays.asList()` at each loop turn. Since you need to build a list dynamically, you can use directly a `List` instead of an array.

Comment: So I would declare value as 'List value = new ArrayList();' and then 'if (value.contains(arIndex))'?

Comment: only the non duplicate or remove all duplicate value?

Comment: I want only the non duplicate values @igreen...

Comment: So if you have for example "ff" and "ff" you don't want to see in the resulf "ff" at all. am I right?

Comment: so if arIndex =[1,1,2,3]; I want to see arIndex=[1,2,3]; @igreen

Comment: So use HashSet as some other wrote. from your question I understand you only want the values that do NOT have duplication. but you only want to remove duplicate values from you data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with `Strings`, as long as your result doesn't have to account for case sensitive, you can use a HashMap to count your occurrences.  Then when your HashMap is populated, you can iterate through it and move all occurrences whose value is 1 (Not duplicated) to an array (List of some sort).

You'll see in my code sample that each string becomes a key in my HashMap and the count of the key is the value.  I don't care about casing which is why in the results you'll see that Hello and hello are not considered duplicated.  If you want to consider that duplicated then you can modified my sample code to ignore case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] arIndex = new String[] {"the", "the", "1", "2", "Hello", "hello", "2"};
    Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

    // Count occurences of each string in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arIndex.length; i++) {
        if (occurrences.containsKey(arIndex[i])) {
            occurrences.put(arIndex[i], occurrences.get(arIndex[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            occurrences.put(arIndex[i], 1);
        }
    }

    List<String> nonDuplicatesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> occurrence : occurrences.entrySet()) {
        if (occurrence.getValue() == 1) {
            nonDuplicatesList.add(occurrence.getKey());
        }
    }

    // Only do this if you're bounded to an array, otherwise just use the nonDuplicatesList
    Object[] value = nonDuplicatesList.toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
}
```

Results:

[image]

### Update

After seeing your comment, that an array with values [1, 1, 2, 3] should result in [1, 2, 3], the following code change get's you that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] arIndex = new String[] {"the", "the", "1", "2", "Hello", "hello", "2"};
    Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arIndex.length; i++) {
        if (occurrences.containsKey(arIndex[i])) {
            // Ignore this value cause it's a duplicate
            continue;
        } else {
            occurrences.put(arIndex[i], 1);
        }
    }

    arIndex = new String[occurrences.size()];
    occurrences.keySet().toArray(arIndex);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arIndex));
}
```

Results:

[image]

### Update

Another way with just an `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] arIndex = new String[] {"the", "the", "1", "2", "Hello", "hello", "2"};

    List<String> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String arIndex1 : arIndex) {
        if(!removedDuplicates.contains(arIndex1)) {
            removedDuplicates.add(arIndex1);
        }
    }

    // Setting the removedDuplicates to arIndex
    arIndex = new String[removedDuplicates.size()];
    removedDuplicates.toArray(arIndex);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arIndex));
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to count occurences at all in your updated version?

Comment: @Joffrey You don't...  I misread the OPs question that he wanted duplicates removed from source.  I later saw the comment that an array of [1, 1, 2, 3] should result in [1, 2, 3].  I updated my answer for that, but am also leaving my previous sample to support either scenario.

Comment: Also, there is no need to test for key existence, as you're using a map, in which keys are in a set, which does not allow duplicates anyway. But as I said, you don't even need occurences, so the map is not needed, just the set of keys is, so it brings to back to a plain set. Which is what I answered ^^

Comment: Ok I see, well now that you understood the requirements, the code needed is actually much simpler than your current updated version :-)

Comment: Nice example @Shar1er80....but I want to also include `"the"` and `"2"`. The results I'll be looking for will be: `[the, 1, 2, Hello, hello]`

Comment: @yagoTea Look at all of my updates.  The point is pick what you want to do that is easiest for you to understand and grow off of what you can learn from these many choices that you have to implement your solution.  As Joffrey indicated, his answer works great too!  +1 for Joffrey's answer.

Comment: Your last version is nice. It is, I think, the closest to the OP's current state. I still believe a `Set` is more appropriate, but you got my upvote ;-) I suggest you put your last version at the top of your post, btw, since it is the one that actually answers the OP.

Comment: nvm I see your updated comment....thanks @Shar1er80. You, @Joffrey, and @igreen have provided help that is highly appreciative....one last question...I see the `removedDuplicates` have the non duplicate values...how do I set `arIndex` to equal `removedDuplicates`?

Comment: Okay I see the `Map` example is the way to go for me!

Comment: @yagoTea updated answer (2nd & 3rd Update) to set results back to arIndex.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are statically allowed, with a fixed size. Collections are more appropriate in java, and available in the `java.util` package. You'll find the most common data structures, such as lists, queues, sets, maps etc.

In your specific case, you should use [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which **inherently removes duplicates**.
So you would just add everything to it with the [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) method, and duplicates would be automatically ignored:

```
String arIndex[] = new String[rows];
// arIndex is probably filled with something useful here

Set<String> output = new HashSet<>(); // this set will hold your non-duplicated elements

for (String s : arIndex) { 
    output.add(s); // add() ignores the element if already present
}

// now output contains all your values only once:
for (String s : output) { 
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

---

Then, if you really need the output as an array (which you actually should not need), you can use the following after the loop:

```
String[] outputArray = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
```

Comment: The non-duplicates will be in the `output` set

Comment: I added a printing loop at the end so that you can see the content of `output`

Comment: Okay and I can set the arIndex array to equal the output list by doing this: asIndex[i] = output;

Comment: You can't do that. What is `i` here? If you want to replace your former array, you can use the last line I wrote: `asIndex = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);` but why do you need this to be an array?

Comment: I have multiple values being stored inside a database and i need to make sure that there are no duplicates, and `i` is the loop count

Comment: You don't need to change anything inside the loop I gave you, because you would be operating on the set while it is not finished. Storing things in a database is one thing, but I don't understand why you want to use an array in Java. You can store whatever you want in your database, you don't need an array here.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for beginners - try not to bring your experience but enjoy Java. Don't use arrays - use Collections. Don't check what is already checked - duplication in particular. Then your code will look like Java code:

```
TreeSet<String> set=new TreeSet<String>(); // TreeSet has no duplication
set.add(value); //  add something
set.addAll(anotherSet); // better choice
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that arrays are objects too and they are immutable in length. Adding/removing one element actually means that you create new array with different size, copy old one, add new elements, delete old array. As you can see it is very expensive.